# How to fix GeometryControls#getInfoWindowHtml says: failed to get html from template error?

Tags: google-maps, polygon, google-maps-api-2

I have downloaded source files of gmaps utility library example for drawing polygon from following link.
[gmaps-utility-library](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geometrycontrols/)

But when I executed those files in my localhost, It's showing me following error:

```
GeometryControls#getInfoWindowHtml says: failed to get html from template
```

This problem is coming because of following code from map_main.js

```
 geometryControls.addControl(markerControl);
 geometryControls.addControl(polygonControl);
 geometryControls.addControl(polylineControl);
 map.addControl(geometryControls);
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is API V2, not V3. Where are you implementing it, and what API version are you loading?

Comment: i want to implement it in user registration form.

Comment: Not enough information. Please post your complete page.